# Implement google calendar in app for booking events by client

Tags: google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I wanted to create a meeting scheduler which clients can see my calendar and select the free date. But I couldn't find this way anywhere. I used google service account and it showed me empty list, someone said you need to share the calendar with the service account but I couldn't find an option there to share it. I also found this '

```
$login_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=' . urlencode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar') . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode(CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL) . '&response_type=code&client_id=' . CLIENT_ID . '&access_type=offline&prompt=consent';
```

which we can use to login but, but it is not good when I want to create a new event with API

please if you have a solution tell me

I used google service account, and

```
$login_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=' . urlencode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar') . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode(CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL) . '&response_type=code&client_id=' . CLIENT_ID . '&access_type=offline&prompt=consent';
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have shared a calendar with a service account, the service account should accept the invitation. To do that you only have to add the calendar to the service account `My Calendars` list.

You have two options to accomplish the above. If you want to keep using the PHP Calendar API you can use the [`CalendarList.insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) method. Additionally, since this operation needs to be done just once, you can do it on the Calendar user interface. Let me know in a comment below if you need further clarifications.

Comment: But I couldn't share the Calendar with write permission. it just access read permission, also where I can confirm the invitation for the service account?

Comment: Permission to read is enough in this case. Once you have invited the service account, you should use the method [`CalendarList.insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) on the service account to add it to the `My Calendars` list.